# Unable to change values of elements around a point in a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am currently coding a program that will run minesweeper in java, but this certain section has been giving me issues.  I am trying to edit a small 2d array, like: { { 0, -1 }, { 0, 0 } };  and it should edit it into a field that looks like this: { { 1, -1 }, { 1, 1 } };  but is currently not changing any of the values as far as I can tell. Basically, I am just trying to add 1 to the eight cells surrounding a bomb (value of -1), unless that cell is itself a bomb (-1), but have not had any luck so far. I would greatly appreciate any help you could offer!

```
public static void setHint(int[][] field)
{
    for (int x=0; x < field.length - 1; x++) {
      for (int y=0; y < field[0].length - 1; y++) {
          if (field[x][y] == -1) {
              if (field[x-1][y-1] != -1) {
                  field[x-1][y-1]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x-1][y+1] != -1) {
                  field[x-1][y+1]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x+1][y-1] != -1) {
                  field[x+1][y-1]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x+1][y+1] != -1) {
                  field[x+1][y+1]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x-1][y] != -1) {
                  field[x-1][y]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x+1][y] != -1) {
                  field[x+1][y]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x][y-1] != -1) {
                  field[x][y-1]  += 1;
              }
              if (field[x-1][y-1] != -1) {
                  field[x-1][y-1]  += 1;
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

field.length is 2. So condition `x < field.length -1` is only true for `x=0`. The same for `y`. So you only evaluate the field `(0,0)`. Since the value of `field[0][0]` is 0, the if condition is false so nothing is executed.

So you can start by changing the end condition of the loops:

```
for (int x=0; x < field.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < field[0].length; y++) {
```

You also have to verify if you are not testing outside the matrix. When x=0, checking on field[x-1][y] will result in an IndexOutOfBoundException and this will be the case for all fields at the sides (where x=0, x=length-1, y=0,y=length-1)

Comment: That's what I had assumed went wrong, I went back and edited it so that it should take care of that issue as well as the IndexOutOfBoundException, but now I continue to have trouble getting around the IndexOutOfBoundException. I changed each if statement to look like this:        if ((field[x-1][y-1] != -1) && (x-1 >= 0) && (y-1 >= 0) && (x-1 < field.length) && (y-1 < field.length)) {      but I still run into an error with that.  I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: change the order of you conditions in your test. In java when you test `A && B` and condition A evaluates false, B is not evaluated. So you have to check on `x-1>=0`before you use it as array index. So your `if` should be `if ((x-1>=0) && (y-1>=0) && (field[x-1][y-1]!=-1))`

Comment: That fixed the issue! Thank you so much for helping! I am a fairly new programmer and I really appreciate the help to fix issues like these!